# is KMS-Digital-Online_Activation_Suite safe valid and genuine to activate windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I bought Windows 10 Pro Key online through Lazada, the seller gave me a product key but upon activation it failed to activate the system.

I asked the seller for some help and then he gave me a link to download some files and open it to automatically activate the system.

I read the `ReadMe.text` file and found this line `This tool is the fork of mephistooo2 KMS-Digital-Online_Activation_Suite`. I started to think if he is tricking me because as far as I know, using KMS to activate windows is illegal.

Anyway, I downloaded the file and run a security scan and the result is 0 threat found.

Comment: The file you were sent is NOT a Microsoft application and should not be used.  The seller is not authorized to sell Microsoft products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KMS is a standard Windows activation mechanism used for "volume" licenses. That is, instead of performing a permanent activation bound to the computer, it's a license server that issues 120-day activations for all PCs on a corporate network.

So KMS itself is not illegal – but the illegal part that you're describing comes from installing a fake KMS server to provide licenses that you don't actually own. *(I don't know the specifics of MS licensing, but selling 'real' KMS activations off a real server to third parties is most likely not permitted either.)*

The attached archive appears to do something very similar. The script mostly just runs some built-in Windows tools and configures a generic product key that tells Windows to use KMS, but it does not install a local fake KMS server nor does it configure any specific remote KMS server to be used (e.g. over the Internet).

However, the included slc.dll is unsigned, suspiciously short, and consists mostly of functions which do nothing. In other words, it has been patched to always generate a "successful KMS activation" ticket without ever contacting a KMS server at all. So I'm 99% sure that you were sent a crack.

Although this doesn't imply that the license key you've bought is garbage, it's very likely to be.

Comment: Worth pointing out that, Windows Server itself, would act its own Key Management Server (KMS) once you configure it as such.  Offline activation is possible, with an initial challenge and response, Windows would activate the same way it activates when it contacts Microsoft.  So KMS isn’t an application or a script which is how we know what you were sent is legitimate

Comment: Does connecting and activating to a custom KMS Server allow the Server owner to access my machine ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The server is only able to provide a basic "activation result" response.

Answer (score 3):

Key Management Service (KMS) is used to activate Microsoft products on clients using generic keys against a Volume Activation Service, hosted on a remote server. Legally owned volume licenses are installed on the server and activation is required typically every 180 days to keep the products activated on client machines.
For more information, please refer to the
[Understanding KMS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793434.aspx)
article by Microsoft.

Hacking tools using KMS activation emulate a fake KMS server on the local computer and trick Microsoft products to activate against it. Products activated this way have temporary valid license and when installing such hack tools, a task is often created to automatically renew it every 60 days.

In my opinion, Lazada has taken your money and gave you a hacking tool,
which by itself is dangerous to use as it might install unknown software
on your computer.
The product key you received is probably for KMS activation, so cannot be
used by itself for normal Windows activation.

I'm afraid your money is lost.
I recommend looking for a legitimate seller of Microsoft licenses.

Comment: Does connecting and activating to a custom KMS Server allow the Server owner to access my machine ?

Comment: @techno: Software Installed from sources you don't trust can do anything it likes.

Comment: I was just referring to this `slmgr /ipk yourlicensekey
slmgr /skms kms8.site.com
slmgr /ato` . Not software from custom sources.

Comment: @techno: The problem is the server you are connecting to, if this is a dummy server that was installed by some doubtful application.

Comment: Eg: The server is hosted in the web by an unknown entity.The user simply use these commands for activation from legitimate OS.Does the attacker get access to the user's machine ?

Comment: @techno: This is different from the situation in the post. As the KMS request is via TCP, the only danger is that the cloud server will detect your IP address (or rather the router's) and Windows version, and will be able use this to attack both. The risk is low (but not zero) if all software is recent and up to date.